# Boolean regression or similar algorithm

Tags: algorithm, boolean, artificial-intelligence, linear-regression

I'm looking to take in a set of values and then return a boolean value based on that set.  Similar to linear regression but only returning a boolean value.  Is a boolean regression model what I'm looking for or something completely different?  I performed a few searches on it but didn't come up with much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you want is [classification](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classification_in_machine_learning), which given the input returns a value from a fixed set of values (be it 100 values or just 2 values as is the case with Boolean classification). `Regression` is used if you want to predict a real-valued output.

Comment: Right, so something like a NN or Bayes Network would apply in this case? I guess I will just have to break down the various classification algorithms and determine which one meets my needs for this simple project.

Comment: we have no idea what your needs are.

Comment: Correct; There are quite a few software-packages and libraries which allow you to easily use different classification algorithms, for example: [Weka](http://www.cs.waikato.ac.nz/ml/weka/) (GUI/Java) or [scikit-learn](http://scikit-learn.org/) (Python)

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0AkhGkRcKaAy8dDNJWTlYellXUF9HZG9TNlp6cmZ3ckE#gid=1

So that's an example of the data I want to classify.  Since you are either selected or not-selected, a score really doesn't make much sense for this.  It would read in all the values and predict a select or non-select based on training data.

Comment: Do you also know which ones are selected and non-selected (i.e., you data is labeled)? If you do then you can use [supervised learning](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Supervised_learning) classification algorithm, otherwise you would need [unsupervised learning](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unsupervised_learning) classification algorithms.

Comment: Yes, from past data.  But obviously on current data that's what I'm trying to predict.

Comment: I would suggest to use Weka's Explorer (GUI). First you'll have to convert your data to Weka's `.arff` file format. Then you can perform further preprocessing in Weka after which you can select many different (supervised) classification algorithm. I'd suggest to try some classics: Naive Bayes, LibSVM (svm), J48 (decision tree) and MultiLayerPreceptron (neural network).